# Grails g:remotelink the logout button not working

Tags: java, html, grails

I have created a logout button, which using "post" method.But the problem is the button cannot work. When I click the button, nothing happened. can someone help me with this?

This is my logout button code

```
<body>
  <div id="welcome" class="view"
    <h1>
      Welcome! Login successful.
    </h1>
    <g:remoteLink controller="logout">
      <input type="submit" id="logout" value="Logout" name="logout"/>
    </g:remoteLink>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The remoteLink tag (which is deprecated as of 3.0; you should probably change to something else) only sends an ajax request.  You should either handle the results, or use a non-ajax link instead.

Comment: Thx! I have solved the problem by using get method which is g:link.